# AS3 Class for reading GET vars

Tags: php, actionscript-3, communication, httprequest

When communicating with server via GET to a php script, I need a feedback, usually in the format: status=OK&msg=No further actions&other=blablabla ... so I know that was a successfull request. But AS3 is very object-oriented, so I made a Class to put it in an object:

```
package com.gustavopi.comm {

    public class Vars {

        public var demo:String = new String();
        public var Obj:Object = new Object();
        public var Var:Array = new Array();
        public var Val:Array = new Array();
        public function Vars(strVars:String=null) {
            var Termos:Array = strVars.split("&");
            for(var t in Termos){
                var termo:String = Termos[t];
                var Elem:Array = termo.split("=");
                Obj[Elem[0]] = Elem[1];
                Var.push(Elem[0]);
                Val.push(Elem[1]);
                demo += Elem[0]+": "+Elem[1]+String.fromCharCode(13);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

The advantage is quickly detect errors using "demo" method, but the vars are properties of Obj, not of the object itself, wich is a little strange - but works.

I'm not sure if this is the best way to deal with the task or if I did something that already exists in the AS3 core. What do you think about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your variables should start with a lower case whereas the classes start with an upper case.

There are several ways to get some data from a server, yours is the simplest and oldest one. It was commonly used with AS2. That is exactly why there is already a class to handle this:

```
var urlVariables:URLVariables = new URLVariables("firstName=Tom&lastName=Jones");
trace(urlVariables.lastName + "," + urlVariables.firstName); 
//will trace "Jones,Tom"
```

Check out the [AS3 URLVariables class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLVariables.html).

Comment: You're right. This class is quite flexible and very handy in fact.

Comment: How do you know I'm old AS2 coder??? And your solutiom was under my nose since I use it to send vars, but didn't know it could be used to receive vars into an object. Thanks! About the upper case: I like to use it for Objects and Arrays, but in this case is strange - now is too late...